trigger callback when error comes from clientside i.e browser console in dash app
I have an requirement, i want to capture errors from a client-side console and display them in a Dash app using client-side callbacks. for example when server is down or proxy is turned off whatever we get errors in browser console, i want to display them in dash app,
I tried the following code but not working,

error.js

 const originalFetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = function() {
    return originalFetch.apply(this, arguments)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                var errorMessage = '403 Forbidden Error detected';
                // alert(errorMessage);
                sendErrorToDash(errorMessage);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            var errorMessage = 'Fetch error: ' + error.message;
            // alert(errorMessage);
            // window.dash_clientside.clientside.get_error_function(errorMessage);
            sendErrorToDash(errorMessage);
            throw error;
        });
};

function sendErrorToDash(errorMessage) {
    var errorStore = document.querySelector('#error-handler');
    if (errorStore) {
        errorStore.textContent = errorMessage;
        var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
        errorStore.dispatchEvent(event); // Trigger an 'input' event
    }
}


app.py

app.layout = html.Div([
html.Div(id='error-handler', style={'display': 'none'}),
html.Div(id='user_notification')

 ])


app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function geterrorfromjs(errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage)
        return errorMessage
    }
    """,
    Output(usernotification, 'children'),
    Input('error-store', 'value')  
)


You want to capture errors when the user does something manually in the console, rather than errors generated by the script?

i want to capture error from browser console like fetch error or 403 kinda errors

try/catch will catch synchronous errors. When using promises, use .catch()
